# How to make my code dealing with calculations based on data from large data sets faster in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a code in which I have input data of size 50000x20 matrix (50000 blocks , 20 properties each). I then calculations to decide the block I would select to move based on some calculations for which I have to run the loop over all blocks. Then I make the some changes to a characteristic value (a different variable )for this block and repeat the same process over and over.
Is do the calculations for each block inside the loop. Is calling a function a better and faster way to do it?
This code is running without converging (based on some convergence criteria) for long. How so I deal with this?
Is this approach of dealing with large data sets good. Can I do better? Please help.

Thanks
Surendra

Comment: If done properly, I don't think that calling a function would noticeably impact performance either way. It may, however, help make the code more readable.

Comment: If you'd like specific help, I suggest you show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function helps with readability and can *potentially* even slow down your code if it's called extensively and is not `inline`.

You need to do **benchmarking** and determine what your bottlenecks are and also take a look at [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), it could be of help to you.

Would also help to post some code :).

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the characteristic value for block affect the other blocks?

If not, then there's probably no need to repeat the calculations for the other blocks.